# Saving application data when closed using MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, save

The issue I am having right now is saving data of my applications when I exit. I am using the MVVM pattern to create this application. The application is a simple DataGrid which is bound to a list of Users which are of type TestModel that has a Name, Last Name, Department and an ID.

```
public ObservableCollection<TestModel> Users { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Users.Add(
            new TestModel { ID = 1, NAME = "George", LastName = "Williams"});
        Users.Add(
            new TestModel { ID = 2, NAME = "Bob", LastName = "Smith"});
    }

<DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

I implemented another view to add a new User to the list as well as a 3rd view to edit the details about the selected user. Everything works fine.

The issue now is that when I exit my application, all of the Users I created during the session are gone, the data is not saved permanently, only those Users which I created in the MainWindowViewModel constructor remain on launch. How can I save the data permanently so the Users I add during a session are there when I launch again? I am not using a database.

Comment: _"I am not using a database"_ - I feel like you buried the lede there. If you want the data to be actually saved, _use a database_. Otherwise it's just stored in-memory, and lost on restart.

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe on this one; a database, a csv, an xml, or any other mode of persisting data

Comment: It's up to you to determine how you wish to save your runtime data. Do you save it into a SQLite database, application configuration file, CSV text file? The list is pretty extensive although some solutions will require more coding than others and some may be limited by your platform.

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question. Basically, you're asking "how to save data somewhere and reload it, automatically, or manually ?". There are several ways to achieve this (database, local binary, local text file, serialization, application data, clouds, services, even registry...) and each of them takes dozens if not hundreds of forms of implementation. The better ? None of them, it all depends on what you need for what purpose under what level of security/safety (such as sensible data, and data loss concerns).

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. When I add items to the list, what is the simplest way for those items to be saved permanently and not be deleted upon exit. I see suggestions of csv and xml, I will look more into that

Comment: There is a function like dispose where executes when your program closes there you can save all data. Or you safe it directly when the data addeded to the list